# Class paths of PlayDependencyClassLoader

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, classloader

For a plugin architecture with on the fly compilation I need to get the class paths of loaded dependencies in a play app.

Play inherits a URLClassLoader for source dependencies, which is reloaded on demand, with a PlayDependencyClassLoader as parent loader. It's easy to find information for the URLClassLoader, but not so much for the PlayDependencyClassLoader, which directly inherits ClassLoader.

How I would I do that? My backup solution would be to parse the toString() representation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my backup solution parsing toString():

```
public class PlayClassPathExtractor {
    public Set<String> getClassPaths(ClassLoader loader) {
        String repr = loader.toString();
        // repr is like "PlayDependencyClassLoader{/class/path.jar, /other/class/path}"
        if (!repr.startsWith("PlayDependencyClassLoader")) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        String[] nameAndRest = repr.split("\\{"); // ["PlayDependencyClassLoader", ".6..}"]
        repr = nameAndRest[1];
        String[] urls = repr.split("(\\}|,\\s*)");
        Set<String> classPaths = new HashSet<>();
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                classPaths.add(new URL(url).getFile());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Failed to parse.. just ignore this one
            }
        }

        return classPaths;
    }
}
```